# copy from char* to char[]

Tags: c++, cstring

is there any way to copy from char* to char[] other than using strcpy?
I tried this and does not work.. 
for ex

```
char* t1 = "hello";
char t2[6];
t2 = t1;
```

It is not compiling.. saying that incompatible types of assignment of 'char*' to char[6]

Thank you

Comment: You can also use `memcpy()`... :) Is there a reason why you can't use `strcpy()`?

Comment: Or a reason you can't use std::string ? std::string t2; t2 = t1; would work.

Comment: It should be `const char * t1 = "hello";`, with the const.

Comment: Please avoid `strcpy` if at all possible, since it behaves badly with incorrect input. Use `strncpy` instead, so you don't have an overflow.

Comment: Arrays are not able to be assign copied in C++.  You have to use a lower level function to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/):

```
strncpy(t2, t1, 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing first  - you cannot do `char* t1 = "hello";`; Simply because string literals are constant, and any attempt to modify them trough `t1` will result in undefined behavior.

Since C++ doesn't have assignment operators from constant character pointer to character array, you have to copy memory manually. [`memcpy`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), [`memmove`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memmove.3.html), [`strcpy`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) or [`strncpy`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) are your standard options, and you can always write your own (which I don't recommend you doing).

Comment: Well, you **can**, but the resulting char buffer will be implicitly `const`.

Comment: I think he wants to copy it leaving the original string literal intact.

Comment: <quote>you cannot do</quote>. You obviously can. But I think the statement you are looking for is **you should not do**.

Answer (score 1):

You need `strcpy`. Arrays in C++ (an C) have a pointer to the first item (character in this case).

So `strcpy(t2, t1)` will do the trick.

*Also - being perdantic you need `const char * const t1 = "hello"` - but the standard gives a lot of tolerance on that subject.*

Comment: IIRC, the standard gives the tolerance to the compilers, not the end programmer.

Comment: strcpy is unsafe, and can lead to buffer overruns.  Start him off with strncpy.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can also use `copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(t1, t1 + 6, t2);
```

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: You can use `std::min((sizeof t2) - 1, std::strlen(t1))` if you prefer and add a trailing zero manually.

Comment: No. Use the functions designed for this: strncpy(). We already know that the C-String handling feature are inherently unsafe and thus you take a closer look at features that use/see them. using std::copy() sort of gives it an air of acceptability that makes you worry less. I would prefer to worry more that the author is using unsafe techniques so I can convert to std::string quicker.

Comment: @LokiAstari: The OP said explicitly "other than strcpy". I assumed that "strncpy" was subsumed in that condition.

Answer (score 1):

To be supersafe, you should use `strncpy` to copy and `strnlen` to get the length of the string, bounded by some MAX_LENGTH to protect from buffer overflow.

```
char t2[MAX_LENGTH];
strncpy(t2, t1, strnlen(t1, MAX_LENGTH))
```

Remember, that `t1` is only a pointer - a number that points you to some place in memory, not an actual string. You can't copy it using assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* t1 = "hello";
char t2[6];
memcpy(t2, t1, 6);
```

Or

```
char* t1 = "hello";
char t2[6] = { t1[0], t1[1], t1[2], t1[3], t1[4], t1[5] };
```

Comment: I understand it is not the point of the question, but beware multibyte characters in string literals when assessing that, say, "hello" is 6 bytes long.